# Temporary storage used by google-BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

As data is written to BigQuery tables, it is buffered on a temporary area in a chosen bucket before writing to a table. As concurrency of writes increase the performance of this temporary storage becomes important. What optimization can be done to increase this buffer-write performance? For example, can Solid State Disk be used for temporary storage?

Thanks

Comment: How you are writing data to BigQuery tables ? Are you using Dataflow or BQ scripts or any other Data pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Data is written through Spark structured streaming with source being Kafka and sink being BigQuery.

Regardless I think the only viable alternative is to use multiple temporary storage for different applications?